# Python automatic Bordering Issue

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a top and bottom border around the characters of a word or certain statement. I understand how to do it manually by if codes, but I am not sure how to create a function in which it will automatically border it without inputting the # of characters.

ex. 
Input:

```
>>> Border("StackOverFlow")
```

Desired Output:

```
=============
StackOverFlow
=============
```

Comment: The number of characters is the `len(..)` of the string...

Comment: I realize that, but how can I communicate that to create that # of "=" characters

Comment: Well, how do you do it otherwise?

Comment: `'='*n` with `n` the number of characters.

Comment: otherwise I had just  used

Comment: def Border (Name):
    if len(Name) == 1:
        print("=")
        print(Name)
        print("=")
    if len(Name) == 2:
        print("==")
        print(Name)
        print("==")
    if len(Name) == 3:
        print("===")
        print(Name)
        print("===")

Comment: so set the len(name) = n and use n to multiply the = ?

Answer (score 2):

```
def borderize(string):
    return '{0}\n{1}\n{0}'.format('='*len(string), string)

print borderize('strackoverflow')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Border(content):
    print("="*len(content) + "\n" + content + "\n" + "="*len(content))
```

In python, `*` can be multiplication but it can also be repetition, as demonstrated here. `"="*10` means repeat the character `"="` ten times.

Comment: what does the str do? and so to use the split line I just need to put the \n in quotation?

Comment: oops, the `str` is redundant. It casts it to a string. and `\n` is the escape sequence line feed. You can read more about these escape sequences[here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: awesome! Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to clear it up.

```
def Border(text):
    # First border,
    length = len(text)
    print('='*length)
    # Now for the text,
    print(text)
    # Second border,
    print('='*length)
```

You could even add more decorations like so:

```
def Border(text):
    text = '* ' + text + ' *'
    length = len(text)
    print('='*length)
    print(text)
    print('='*length)
```

**Why it works:**

We first get the length of the string, `length = len(text)`. By doing this, we can effectively get how long our borders should be.

Then we can print the borders by using `'='*length`, this prints a single '`=`' multiplied by `length`.

Python can use multiplied strings as patterns, *e.g.* `'123'*3` `->` `123123123`. In our case, we only want to multiply one character, so: `'='*10` `->` `==========`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def border(a):
    return '='*len(a) + '\n' + a + '\n' + '='*len(a)


>>> print(border('StackOverFlow'))

=============
StackOverFlow
=============
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].